# Formating csv file to utilize zabbix sender

Tags: python, zabbix

I have a csv file that i need to format first before i can send the data to zabbix, but i enconter a problem in 1 of the csv that i have to use.

This is a example of the part of the file that i have problems:

```
    Some_String_That_ineed_01[ifcontainsCell01removehere],xxxxxxxxx02
    Some_String_That_ineed_01vtcrmp01[ifcontainsCell01removehere]-[1],aass
```

so this is 2 lines from the file, the other lines i already treated.
i need to check if Cell01 is in the line

```
    if 'Cell01' in h: do something.
```

i need to remove all the content beetwen the [ ] included this [] that contains the Cell01 word and leave only this:

```
    Some_String_That_ineed_01,xxxxxxxxx02
    Some_String_That_ineed_01vtcrmp01-[1],aass
```

else my script already treats quite easy. There must be a better way then what i think which is use h.split in the first [ then split again on the , then remove the content that i wanna then add what is left sums strings. since i cant use replace because i need this data([1]).

later on with the desired result i will add this to zabbix sender as the item and item key_. I already have the hosts,timestamps,values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a regexp (re module):

```
import re

s = "Some_String_That_ineed_01[ifcontainsCell01removehere],xxxxxxxxx02"
replaced = re.sub('\[.*Cell01.*\]', '', s)

print (replaced)
```

will return:

```
[root@somwhere test]# python replace.py
Some_String_That_ineed_01,xxxxxxxxx02
```

You can also experiment [here](https://regex101.com/r/0QRfX2/1).

Comment: thanks  i will try to implement your solution. i always forget how to regex.